# Gender Count after inner joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I inner joined three tables CC, Students, and Teachers using the code below:

```
SELECT  CC.Course_number , CC.Expression, teachers.Lastfirst, students.gender, teachers.sched_department
From CC
inner join students  ON CC.StudentID=students.ID
inner join teachers  ON CC.TeacherID=Teachers.ID
Where CC.SchoolID=151 and CC.TermID=2401
Order by teachers.sched_department, CC.course_number,  Teachers.Lastfirst, CC.Expression, students.gender
```

The code works where I get a list that includes the course code, course period, teacher name, department and gender.

However the output I am hoping for is a condensed format that is as follows:

`Course Number` (once) from CC table, `Course Expression` from CC table, `Teacher` from Teacher table, `Department` from Teacher table, `Male` (count in that specific class) from student table, `Female` (count in that specific Class) from Student table.

The last code I tried was this:

```
SELECT
CC.Course_number , CC.Expression, teachers.Lastfirst, teachers.sched_department, male_cnt, female_cnt
From CC
inner join teachers 
ON CC.TeacherID = Teachers.ID
inner join (Select students.ID, count(case when students.gender= 'M' then students.ID end) as male_cnt, count(case when students.gender= 'F' then students.ID end) as female_cnt
From Students
Where
students.SchoolID=151
Group By students.ID) 
ON CC.StudentID=students.ID
Where CC.SchoolID=151 and CC.TermID=2401
Order By 
teachers.sched_department, CC.course_number,  Teachers.Lastfirst, CC.Expression
```

Any suggestion will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table structure, and sample input/output data it's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're looking for, but maybe this is what you want? If it's not, please clarify your requirements and add sample data.

```
SELECT 
    CC.Course_number, 
    CC.Expression, 
    Teachers.Lastfirst, 
    Teachers.sched_department, 
    SUM(students.gender = 'male') AS males,
    SUM(students.gender = 'female') AS females
FROM CC
INNER JOIN Students ON CC.StudentID = students.ID
INNER JOIN Teachers ON CC.TeacherID = Teachers.ID
WHERE CC.SchoolID = 151 and CC.TermID = 2401
GROUP BY 
  CC.Course_number, 
  CC.Expression, 
  Teachers.Lastfirst, 
  Teachers.sched_department
ORDER BY 
  teachers.sched_department, 
  CC.course_number, 
  Teachers.Lastfirst, 
  CC.Expression
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ac9a/2) (with a lot of assumptions about table structure...)

Comment: shortcut, IFNULL() should not be needed since it is a join to the student table unless the gender is actually null.  Also, a logical TRUE condition returns 1 else 0, so it could be ex: sum( students.gender = 'male' ) Count_Of_Male  -- similar for female counts

Comment: @DRapp Good points, I used only used the ifnull to prettify the results (by replacing null with 0).